# Who is this to me?

Tags: family

Your mum's brother's, wife's, father in law's, son in law's, daughter's, husband's, mother in law's, son in law's, father in law's, wife's, brother's, wife's, brother is who to you?

Comment: An excellent source of unsubstantiated rumours.  Or, at least, his dog is.

Comment: [Obligatory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=riqXhieWU3M)

Comment: Or even https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYlJH81dSiw

Answer (score 10):

Your mum's brother's,

> Your uncle’s

wife's,

> Aunt by marriage’s

father in law's,

> (Mom’s Dad’s) Grandfather’s

son in law's,

> Dad’s

daughter's,

> Sister’s

husband's,

> Brother in law’s

mother in law's,

> Mom’s

son in law's,

> Brother in law’s

father in law's,

> Dad’s

wife's,

> Mom’s

brother's

> Uncle’s

wife's

> Aunt’s

brother

> Uncle in law? I suppose? It could be your aunt by marriage’s brother, but this is far from unique — this puzzle doesn’t necessarily have a unique solution depending on the size of the family

Comment: Kinda makes your head spin, but at least we came to the same conclusion.

Comment: Yes, agreed — thought I had done something funny, as well but was good seeing your answer!

Comment: not always true. For example my father's (second) wife is not my mother. My grandfather's son isn't necessarily my dad, it could be my uncle. Etc

Comment: Exactly — hence my comment that “this is far from unique — this puzzle doesn’t necessarily have a unique solution depending on the size of the family” @KateGregory

Answer (score 8):

> Mum's brother's, wife's, father in law is your maternal grandfather. His son in law is either your father or the husband of an aunt. Either way, the daughter's, husband's, mother in law's, son in law's, father in law is that same man, and his wife's brother is your mother's brother, your uncle. Your uncle's wife's brother is of no direct relation to you.

Answer (score 2):

Same answer as the previous responses, but I made a little table, since I cannot do anything without a visualisation.

Legend:

- M/F refer to gender
- Y is 'you'
- vertical connections are always parental
- horizontal connections are either marriage ('m') or sibling ('s')

> [image: Spoiler Warning!]

And the chart for fishinear's suggested relationship:

> [image: Spoiler Warning!]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that:

> Your sister married your uncle

it is:

> You

As such:

> Your mum's brother's: your uncle -  wife's: your sister and aunt - 
>  father in law's: your grandfather -  son in law's: your father - 
>  daughter's: your sister -  husband's: your uncle -  mother in law's:
>  your mother -  son in law's: your sister's husband / your uncle - 
>  father in law's: your father -  wife's: your mother -  brother's: your
>  uncle -  wife's: your sister / aunt -  brother: you

Comment: Technically correct, but ew.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is enough information provided, because I sketched it out

> and all 14 steps can refer to new people not yet accounted for:
>  [image: draw.io diagram of very extended family]
>  Are we supposed to assume the minimum possible family tree? Because I did the opposite!
>  I don't think there's a single name for this person, but the closest I can come up with is uncle's daughter's mom's other child's father's brother-in-law's brother-in-law. That, or "the first person to contact you after you win the lottery."

Edit: because I can't comment yet. The existing answers make a lot of assumptions which lead them to a specific answer, but you can't just choose an answer you like and work back. For example:

> The current top answer says that the first son-in-law is your dad, ignoring the fact that your grandpa can have many different children.

Comment: Some of the references are ambiguous, but in the end point to specific relationship. See my answer or that of El-Guest

Comment: @Daniel Mathias woops, I guess I *can* comment on my own answer. How do you know that your grandfather's son-in-law refers to [deleting spoiler that was misattributed anyway]?

Comment: @DanielMathias I see your answer did not make exactly that claim, but you do make the claim that a later person must be that same man, which is not true

Answer (score 0):

Your mum's brother is

> Your uncle

His wife is

> Your aunt

Her father in law is

> A grandfather

His son in law is

> Your unkle

His daughter is

> A cousin

Her husband is

> A cousin

Her mother in law is

> Your aunt

Her son in law is

> A cousin

His father in law is

> Your unkle

His wife is

> Your aunt

Her brother is

> Your unkle

His wife is

> Your aunt

Her brother is

> Your unkle